# How do I find out if a value is in a deque?

Tags: python, queue, deque

say i have a deque with values [0,3,5,1,5,8]. I want to save all information about the deque including order, but I have to find if the value 5 is in the deque.

What is some pseudo-code that could determine this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you aware of the `in` operator?

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.deque([0,3,5,1,5,8])
>>> 5 in d
True
>>> 20 in d
False
```

Comment: what would be a good implementation of `list.index()` like function for `collections.deque`? Thanks

Comment: What about the time complexity of the operation

Answer (score 3):

Although most of the time you'd want to use the `in` operator for membership testing, which `deque`s support, you also have the option of using its `count()` method — which actually provides *more* information and so might be more useful depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.deque([0, 3, 5, 1, 5, 8])
>>> d.count(5)
2
>>> d.count(20)
0
>>> bool(d.count(5))
True
>>> bool(d.count(20))
False
```